# RegEx - need to remove all but sequences of words, allowing one space to continue words

Tags: regex

Running into a problem while trying to remove spaces and tabs from a collection of names in a html doc.

Ex:

```
        FU BAR       
RE BAR          NULL
```

I need my response to simply be:

```
FU BAR RE BAR NULL
```

I have been attempting:

```
[^A-Z]+([[A-Z]{1,}\s]+)[\s\r\n\t]+
```

and still end up with some straggling spaces or tabs left in. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use: `s/\s+/ /g`?

Oh, just realized that doesn't account for leading and trailing spaces. You can take care of those too by running the input through this regex first, then the one above:

```
s/^\s+|\s+$//
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just replacing `\s+` with a single space? (Assuming we're not constrained to single-line matching).

(If we're using some line-by-line regex replace, such as some Unix tool, we'd nuke all leading and trailing whitespace, replace interior whitespace regions with a single space, and delete lines that are empty or contain only whitespace.)

Are you trying to apply this to some parts of a HTML document while preserving whitespace in other areas? If so, please update your question with an example which reflects this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java,

```
String normalizeSpace = str.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

[Commons Lang 2.6](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) in the class [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) contains the method `normalizeSpace` with the same function (inclusive control characters, char <= 32).